# Did James Madison sign all copies of the Bill of Rights?

Tags: united-states, 18th-century, constitution

I'm aware that James Madison wrote the Bill of Rights but then 13 copies were distributed to the 13 original colonies to review and edit. Is it James Madison's signature on the copies that were sent out?

Comment: Madison was the principle author, however, the 12 proposed amendments were offered to the states by Congress, after editing and approval. There were only 11 states at the time of proposal.. NC, RI and VT voted on the amendments after becoming part of the Union later. states did not review and edit, only ratified or rejected. ..